# (iOS) Spotify Redirect URI Error: SpotifyLogin.LoginError.invalidUrl

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0, spotify

I am trying to implement Logging in With Spotify using [Spotify's Sample Project](https://github.com/spotify/SpotifyLogin). It keeps failing

Not really sure what could be the issue as I am following all of the instructions:

- My redirect url `spotifyApp://spotify-login-callback` is registered properly under Redirect URI
- My URL Scheme is `spotifyApp`
- My Client ID & Secret were Copy Pasted as shown on Developer Console

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let redirectURL: URL = URL(string: "spotifyApp://spotify-login-callback")!
        SpotifyLogin.shared.configure(clientID: "#####1",
                                      clientSecret: "#####1",
                                      redirectURL: redirectURL)
        return true
    }
```

As a user, I am taken to the Spotify Authorization Page and redirected back to the app, with no change in UI and the error

`SpotifyLogin.LoginError.invalidUrl`

**UPDATE**

In the source code for `SpotifyLogin`, it shows that `invalidUrl` means `The url provided to the app can not be handled or parsed.`

This is the code returning the error

```
    /// Process URL and attempts to create a session.
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - url: url to handle.
///   - completion: Returns an optional error or nil if successful.
/// - Returns: Whether or not the URL was handled.
public func applicationOpenURL(_ url: URL, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    guard let urlBuilder = urlBuilder,
        let redirectURL = redirectURL,
        let clientID = clientID,
        let clientSecret = clientSecret else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(LoginError.configurationMissing)
        }
        return false
    }

    guard urlBuilder.canHandleURL(url) else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(LoginError.invalidUrl)
        }
        return false
    }

    safariVC?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    let parsedURL = urlBuilder.parse(url: url)
    if let code = parsedURL.code, !parsedURL.error {
        Networking.createSession(code: code,
                                 redirectURL: redirectURL,
                                 clientID: clientID,
                                 clientSecret: clientSecret,
                                 completion: { [weak self] session, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if error == nil {
                    self?.session = session
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .SpotifyLoginSuccessful, object: nil)
                }
                completion(error)
            }
        })
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .SpotifyLoginSuccessful, object: nil)
            completion(LoginError.invalidUrl)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem was with the redirect URI itself

the URI should NOT have capital letters
And it should just follow this format (no parenthesis)

`((add_your_unique_scheme))://callback/`